Trouble with derivative respecto to relative position vector
Imagine two particles in a three dimensional space, A and B, with position vectors, $\vec{r_A}$ and $\vec{r_B}$. I am doing some calculus in order to get an expression of the potential energy of this system considering a point-delta potential. But I run into the following derivative: $$\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left [ \frac{f(r_A)}{r_A}\right ],$$ where $r=|\vec{r_A} - \vec{r_B}|$. And other similar derivatives for the rest of the spherical coordinates for each particle. Any idea about how to dwell with this little monster? I have thought about using the chain rule, but it is not useful at all.

If you have more information about the function $f$ or the range of $r_A$, you could try replacing $r_A$ on the RHS by either $r+r_B$ or $-r+r_B$ (these equations come from the definition of $r$) and compute the derivative with respect to $r$.
